# JavaScript loop if statement by 5s

Tags: javascript

I can't figure this out. I want **loopCheck** to count by 5s all the way to 500. I know there's an easier way than writing all those numbers out.

```
for (i = 1; i <= 500; i++){
    var loopCheck = i === 5 || i === 10 || i === 15 || i === 20 || i === 25;
    if (loopCheck === true){
        alert("if statement works!!!"):
    }

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For the sake of being different:

You can use the modulo `%` operator:

```
for (i = 1; i <= 500; i++) {
  if (i % 5 === 0) { // if `i` is *perfectly* divisible by 5
    // do something here
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, just what i was looking for. This site is so helpful! :)

Comment: @Matt - Ben's answer below looks better than mine in terms of *code correctness*, for lack of a better word - I'd consider accepting that instead of mine.

Comment: but i dont want to change the for loop i needed to change the if statement and your answer is what did it.

Answer (score 6):

Just add 5 to `i` on each iteration:

```
for (i = 5; i <= 500; i += 5) {
    // ...
}
```

`i += 5` is shorthand for `i = i + 5`. Note that we start with `i` set to 5 here.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the simplicity Bens answer, as an alternative, you can use modulo:

```
for (var i = 1; i <= 500; i++){
   if (i%5 === 0) {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

That maintains the "looping through every number" but with modulo you ask "when I divide the number by 5, what remainder do I have?" If its divisible by 5, you have a remainder of 0. :)